# clicking button jumps to bottom of screen for no reason?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button and when I click it, it opens the popup like its supposed to but it also randomly jumps to the bottom of the page. I can't figure out why.

button html:

```
    <div id="ip" data-clipboard-text="">
                                <button class="myLink" onclick="myFunction()" >PLAY.TITANSCRAFT.COM</button> <i class="fas fa-copy"></i>
                                <p>Click to copy IP address!</p>
                            </div>

script:
```

```
<script>
function copyTextToClipboard(text) {
  var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");

  textArea.value = text;

  document.body.appendChild(textArea);
  textArea.focus();
  textArea.select();

  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
  }

  document.body.removeChild(textArea);
}

var copyBobBtn = document.querySelector('.myLink');

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("modal-alert");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}

copyBobBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  copyTextToClipboard('play.titanscraft.com');
  modal.style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(function(){
    modal.style.display = "none";  
  }, 2000);
});
</script>
```

I'm not very knowledgeable in JavaScript but I don't see anything that could be causing this to occur. 
If you'd like to see the jump to bottom I'm talking about, go to https://www.titanscraft.com/ and click the text in the navigation bar that says "play.titanscraft.com"

Comment: Probably `textArea.focus();`, comment that and see if it still happens.